PowerPoint add-in is getting flagged as potential ransomware threat in my organization when shared on MS Teams
I have a ppam add-in created for PowerPoint and after extensive development, I am ready to launch and deploy across the organization. For testing/pilot, I thought of sharing it via MS teams to a few of my colleagues. But somehow, my IT security team is receiving a potential ransomware threat intimation. IT says they have whitelisted the add-in in their firewall. But still after this, they are getting the same ransomware notifications.
On the contrary, I had digitally signed the add-in with some certificate available in my organization.(Didn't have to find or ask someone for the certificate, but when I tried to sign it, there was one available, so I used that to sign) Not sure how legit is that.
What else can I do here? Are there any other certificates that anyone would recommend?
Thanks in advance!

Having had a similar issue (not ransomware flags, but 'untrusted' and would not allow to enable/install due to being blocked), I had to move several of my addin files to network drives from sharepoint/teams due to people being unable to install.  I did have to edit the properties to unblock the file on the network drive, which allowed usage for all persons.  Regarding the digital signature.,the addins which I'm referring are signed by the vendor and still caused the blocking issue; as such, I have attributed the majority of my issues to sharepoint/teams than to the actual files.
